# Store Items with Categories in FireStore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to firebase and noSQL storage as a whole.
For my small project I want to store many items that all fall into their respective categories.

---

Eg.

- FoodItems

  - Egg
  - Ham
  - Toast
- Animals

  - Frog
  - Penguin

---

The categories themselfes (Animals and FoodItems) do not hold any other information.
How should I store this dataset?

Just Create the Items and give them an attribute "Type"? Or rather have empty documents to store subcollections is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best data model for a NoSQL database depends more on the use-cases you want to implement than on the inherent model of the data itself. Without knowing all the use-cases, I recommend to start with a simple data model, so indeed storing the category in a field (an array field if a food-item can have multiple categories).

To learn more about data modeling in NoSQL databases in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). To learn more about Firestore watch Todd's excellent video series: [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: That does help, thank you! Just if you're interested: The app itself is going to create sentences by using templates. Like "I am hungry for [FoodItem]". For that I need to store all the items and give them a category to be able to retrieve all the possible infills.